# .htacces rewrite if cookie value

Tags: php, cookies

I have a site with a locality that creates a cookie depending on the locality.

The cookie is called: "geodefense" and enters an example value: "peru" but it can deliver many random values depending on the country or province.

I need to redirect for example based on cookie:

Example:

```
https://(*.* url request)/?geo&"cookievalue"
```

or

```
https://(*.* url request)/?geo&"cookievalue"
```

also if the url has other query strings respect them and just add

example:

```
https://(*.* url request)/?"ifthereisanotherquerystringkeep"&"geo&cookievalue"
```

If the URL changes and it detects the cookie it validates that it takes the origin URL and adds? Geo & "cookie value"

And if the cookie does not exist, do nothing and leave the URL as it came in the request

I currently have this code but it does not serve my purposes.

```
 RewriteEngine On 
 #Redirecting with the cookie value
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^geodefense=(peru|piura)$ [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/%1?geo&$1 [R,L]
```

The above code does not work for me because I have to specify which cities are one by one and there are too many.

It is important that you take the value of the cookie and if you don't have it, do nothing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of a way of doing this, although you could create a main proxy like so:

```php
// index.php
$cookie = $_COOKIE["yourCookieNameHere"];

switch ($cookie) {
    case "peru":
        echo file_get_contents("https://{ ... }"); 

        // Or redirect them
        // header("Location: https://{ ... }");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Hello dear
The above code does not work for me because I have to specify which cities are one by one and there are too many.

It is important to extract the value of the cookie is this possible?
The site is cached so you need a querry string to differentiate the URL.

Comment: well, instead of using a switch you could just do something like this,

Comment: file_get_contents("https://" . $prefix . "domain.com");
or a redirect

Comment: Dear this would be in php?
I'm looking for something in .htaccess that prevents contact with the php page before redirecting